# Pass configuration data to Angular service

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I am not sure how it should be done.

I am writing an Angular library. The library has a component and service. Library service needs some configuration data to work. I want to pass this data from the Application which would use this library component. The data would be a JSON data

How I can pass this data? I know @Input can be used in the component. 
is there any other better way to pass the data?
2)

Comment: There are several ways to do it, it depends on the way you get the configuration JSON. By the way, you can always inject a service inside another service. I think it's the most straight-forwarding solution

Comment: If you use redux then you can leverage it

Comment: Do you mean to say Inject External service from the application into a Library service?

Comment: Why are you talking about library services?

Comment: Sorry, If I am not clear. I am creating a library which is a separate module outside. Then there would be an Application project which would import this module. Library module has a service which needs a JSON configuration data to work on.

Comment: Then you can implement the `forRoot` method to pass the configuration. I'm sure that you have already seen it in other big libraries that need configuration, for example google maps

Answer (score 0):

I solved it bypassing the configuration data in the provider.

```
export const columns: Column = {};

 providers: [
{
  provide: CONFIG_DATA, useValue: columns
}
```

]